# How to get pem file in js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pem, server-to-server

I am new to javascript. I am trying to implement [OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) for that i am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-oauth-jwt)  library. So while i was doing this

```
googleAuth.authenticate(
{
email: 'my.gserviceaccount.com',
keyFile: fs.readFileSync("./accesstoken/key.pem"),
scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
}, 
function (err, token) {
  console.log(token);
  console.log("err:"+err);
});
```

it gave me following exception

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----asdasxxx---END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

my file pem.key file is in the same directory in which my js file is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of `fs.readFileSync`

```
keyFile: fs.readFileSync("./accesstoken/key.pem"),
```

Just give simple path to file

```
keyFile: "./key.pem", // if file is in same folder
```

As given in [Original Doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-oauth-jwt) :

```
// the path to the PEM file to use for the cryptographic key (ignored if 'key' is also defined) 
// the key will be used to sign the JWT and validated by Google OAuth 
keyFile: 'path/to/key.pem',
```

Comment: @FaisalAhmed, Glad to know , Happy coding :)